# Java beginner confused about usage of constructors

Tags: java, class, constructor

```
class Date {
    private int year;
    private String month;
    private int day;

    public Date() {
        month = "January";
        year = 1999;
        day = 1;
    }                                  //End of Constructor 1

    public Date(int year, String month, int day) {
        setDate(year, month, day);
    }                                  //End of Constructor 2

    public Date(int year) {
        setDate(year, "January", 1);
    }                                 //End of Constructor 3

    public void setDate(int year, String month, int day) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }                                //End of Constructor 4
}

public class Calendar {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
        Date date1 = new Date(2009, "March", 3);
        Date date2 = new Date(2010);
        Date date3 = new Date();
    }
}
```

In the code above, which constructors are called for date1, date2, and date3? How do you print the results of date1, date2, and date3 after the constructor has been called?

I tried `System.out.println(date1)` and so on but it gives me strange strings like `u.Date@15db9742`.

I was expecting to see 2009 March 1 or something of that sort.

Comment: 1) You should not shadow the builtin Java Date class... 2) You do not have a fourth constructor... That is a method that you call... `new Date().setDate(0, "test", 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to print object, its `toString()` method is called which is inherited by all 
java class from `Object class` (superclass of all java class by default). So you will have to override `toString()` method in your class 
if you need some specific contents of the object to be printed. By default, this method prints 
`Class and its hash code`. Since you have not overriden the `toString()`, the printed string 
contains object class and its hash code ( u.Date@15....).
Your constructor calls are determined by the argument you pass to the constructor.
Like in `date1`, you passed 3 parameter of type `int,string and int` in order.
This matches your constructor 2 arguments which are of `int, string and int`. 
So in in your date1 object consturction, constructor 2 is called.
similarly for date2, constructor 3 is called
and for date3, default constructor i.e consturcot 1 is called.

The "constructor 4" you marked is not a constructor, it is simply a method.
Constructor do not have return type.

Again , to print as you expected in your question, override `toString()` method in your class and format the result accordingly in that method to get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

date1,date2,date3 is an object of a class Date and hence can't be printed. To print it, you will have to override toString() method.

```
String toString() {

 return year + " " + month + " " + day;

}
```

Also, 
Constructors are used to initialize the fields only.

```
public void setDate(int year, String month, int day) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
}                                //End of Constructor 4
```

This method is not a constructor because the constructors always have same name as of the class and have no explicit return type.

Comment: Could you explain how the 4th method has no return type and what the function of this.___ is?

Comment: I said it is not a constructor as it doesn't have the name of the class and has void return type.

Comment: Constructors are used to initialize the instance of the class. Fields are one part of that, but that is not the only function of a constructor.

Comment: @cricket_007 : Yes.

Comment: There is no fourth method. There is only one method in the example `Date` class.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to match the parameters of called constructors with the defined constructors and if you  are not defining any parameters then default constructor will be invoked like

Date date1 = new Date(2009, "March", 3);  it will invoke

```
 public Date(int year, String month, int day) {
        setDate(year, month, day);
    }                                  //End of Constructor 2
```

Date date3 = new Date(); will invoke

```
Public Date() {
        month = "January";
        year = 1999;
        day = 1;
    }                                  //End of Constructor 1
```

Date date2 = new Date(2010); it will invoke

```
public Date(int year) {
    setDate(year, "January", 1);
}                                 //End of Constructor 3
```

Comment: Did you mean  "if you do not define any constructor then a default constructor will be provided"? In the OP's example there are constructors explicitly defined, so no default constructor is provided.

Comment: yes, without constructor object can not be created. if you are not defining any constructor then compiler will provide a default constructor...!